# While registering Get registration datetime and hash it

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, passwords

I just want to hash my user password by taking the registration date_time as a salt. I am going to use this function:

```
function create_hash($pass, $created_date, $hash_method = 'md5') {
// the salt will be the reverse of the user's created date
// in seconds since the epoch
$salt = strrev(date('U', strtotime($created_date));
if (function_exists('hash') && in_array($hash_method, hash_algos()) {
    return hash($hash_method, $salt.$pass);
}
return md5($salt.$pass);
}
```

And also similar method for password verification. But I am thinking about registration process. In my registration form I have only field of username and password and in my mysql database the creation date will be added automatically.

But when first time registration I also need the creation_date for hashing password? How to overcome this? So basically I am imagining I have to get the creation_date before inserting data in the database for salting. How to do this?

One approach I am thinking, in my registration form before calling this function I will do this:

```
$created_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$salt = strrev(date('U', strtotime($created_date));
```

But I am afraid is there going to be a fraction time difference between this salt time and creation_date time of database. If so then my password_validation will not work..

*** BY the way  I know md5() is not secured one. So I dont need suggestion about md5 or other hashing algorithm. I am just interested about salting

Answer (score 0):

Maeby is better idea to write a function that creates a salt

```
function salt($n=3)
{
     $key = '';
     $pattern = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,*_-=+#@!&^%';
     $counter = strlen($pattern)-1;
     for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
     {
         $key .= $pattern{rand(0,$counter)};
     }
     return $key;
}
```

and when new user are registered to call this funtion and do something like this:

```
$salt=salt();
$hash_pass=md5(md5($_POST['password']).$salt);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `my_table` SET `name`='".$_POST["name"]."', `pass`='".$hash_pass."' `regDate`=NOW() ");
```

When the user is loged in, you select the user data from table as name and compare his hashed password with posted password with his salt

Comment: I have my random salt also.. I want to use user creation date as the second salt

Comment: Look how many different functions you cause to create a hashed password, I'm offered with double hashing method that will not consume as much RAM. You can post in your query your variable $date_time and do not call a mysql function NOW() and there will be no difference in time

Comment: It also comes to my mind can I use special character as pepper for md5 hashing. Special character may be tab key, esc key or multiple spaces? if so how to do that? Is it just something like this:    md5('    '.$text);

Comment: I have only one question "WHY???". Suppose your password is "y" (md5(y) = 415290769594460e2e485922904f345d) and your salt is "1" after second hash your password looks like md5('415290769594460e2e485922904f345d'.'1')=d410ed1cc10eadb20711920169535559 can you decrypt this after double hash? Why are you trying to reinvent the bike, but with square wheels???

Answer (score 0):

The best salt you can have, is not derrived from any other parameters, and is not predictable. On a deterministic computer, the best you can do, is getting the salt from the random source of the operating system. This random source will collect real chance from events like user actions, boot time, and much more...

PHP already has a dedicated function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a safe BCrypt hash with such a random salt. It includes the salt into the resulting hash-value, so you can store it into a single field in the database.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Using a pepper can be a good idea as well, but there are better ways to add such a server side secret. Whether your pepper contains special characters or is just longer doesn't matter, the entropy is important. If you are interested you may have a look at my tutorial about [secure password storing](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), on the last pages i tried to explain the pros and cons of a pepper.

Comment: Password_hash is good and easy to implement. . I know that.. but for now I am not interested in password_hash. Trying to strengthen the old md5

Comment: @oxvoxic - An example of how to generate a safe salt you can find [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt), search for the method `generateRandomBase64String()`. I'm interested about your reasons to use MD5, maybe you could explain a bit more? To strengthen this algorithm you must use key-stretching that means using many iterations of MD5, of course i cannot recommend this though.